# Why is my GAN diverging?

Tags: deep-learning, gan

I am trying to train a GAN related to [this](https://github.com/Rudrabha/Wav2Lip) project. At ~100k steps, the discriminator's fake loss suddenly went to 0, and real loss increased very high. (Can look at the plots below). What could be the reason for this?

[image]